# Raphael. Text using the print (). Why not work?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to write text with the print () function. I added cufon file. Unfortunately, the text is not displayed. Why? Please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="harabara.cufonfonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>

        window.onload = function() {

        var r = new Raphael('holder', 640, 480);


    var font1 = r.getFont("Harabara");

    var text1 = r.print(10,100, "click me", font1, 48).attr({"stroke-width": 3, fill: "red", "stroke": "blue"});


     };
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">  
        #holder { width: 640px; height: 480px; border: 2px solid #aaa; }  
    </style>  
   <div id="holder"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see right away:

```
var text1 = r.print(10,100, "click me", font1, 48).attr({"stroke-width": 3, fill: "red", "stroke": "blue"});
```

returns a Raphael path object. So you need to assign that path to your Raphael paper.

> **Paper.print()** Creates path that represent given text written using
>   given font at given position with given size. Result of the method is
>   path element that contains whole text as a separate path.

**http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print**

Have not tested it yet, but just leaving the code the way you wrote will not print anything to the paper.

**One more thing:** keep your `style` tags in your `header`.

Comment: Please give me a correct example of how to do it.

I tried in this way:

                
        var text1path = r.path(text1);

Unfortunately, the text is not displayed.